# Using open system call to open /etc/passwd

Tags: c

I want to read the /etc/passwd file byte by byte and want to display it on std o/p. Here is my code

```
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int fd, ch;
  int ret;
  if((fd = open("/etc/passwd",O_RDONLY)) == -1);
      perror("open");
  while((ret = read(fd, &ch, sizeof(ch))) != 0)
      putchar(ch);

}
```

It compiles properly but it displays open:Success, why an i not able to display the contents, is there anything wrong i have done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be a semicolon after the if's closing parenthesis. That is causing the problem. The semicolon is effectively a null statement which will be executed when the condition is true. Since fd is not equal to -1, perror is called.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `putchar()` is an `int` which has a value in the range of `unsigned char`, so you shouldn't be reading an entire `int` from the file and trying to print that as one character - you should be reading an `unsigned char`.  You can achieve this just by changing the type of `ch` to `unsigned char`.

The extra semicolon at the end of the `if` line is why your `perror()` is appearing even when the `open()` succeeds.